# Why does this code add an additional empty line when using "\n"?

Tags: python, printing

I´m asking about the reason why there is a empty line after printing second block of code.

Code:

```
    print ('a','b', end='', sep='**')
    print('c')
```

Output:

```
a**bc
```

Code:

```
    print ('a','b', end='', sep='**')
    print ('\n')
    print ('c')
```

Output:

```
a**b

c
```

Comment: It can be difficult to show blank lines. Please edit your question to make them obvious, as I could not see where they are.

Answer (score 1):

the default for print is end='\n' so the second line is actually \n\n try using the end='' like you did in the first line